# How to format hard drive without functional OS

Tags: system-installation, format

I was previously dual booting Ubuntu and Windows but by mistake I have deleted a partition. I don't know which one but neither OS is getting loaded.

It is stuck at this scene:

```
Error:unknown file system  
Entering rescue mode....  
Grub rescue>_
```

How to format my hard drive so that I can reinstall those OS again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: I have VTCed as duplicate as you will just need to do a fresh install from a LiveUSB.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I have inserted the cd but the system is not recognising it

Comment: The screen says error unknown file system  entering rescue mode  grub rescue>_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go in your BIOS and change boot order to boot first CD-rom (or bootable USB stick)
2. [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Both Ubuntu and Windows installation applications offer you the option to format hard drive using built in formatting tools, just burn your CD/DVD with installation image of your choice or create installation USB. During the installation process choose to format hard drive.